# Omniauth doesn't return Facebook Checkins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

After authenticating with Omniauth/facebook, checkins dont seem to be included inside the data hash I am receiving from request.env["omniauth.auth"], I have authorized for checkins and can see them fine when hitting the url with my access code..

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at: https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph instead.  Omniauth isn't really intended for scraping all the possible facebook data, just for authenticating.